# C# return Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Im trying to write a method that returns a Dictionary, but it seems like it ends up being empty.
 Can you find out what I am doing wrong ?

When I click the button to search for a Key, It gives Error: Dictionary contains no Keys.

```
class Person
    {
        public int PersNr { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string BioPappa { get; set; }
        public Adress Adress { get; set; }


        public static Dictionary<int, Person> Metod()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, Person>();

            dict.Add(870603, new Person
            {
                Name = "Jonathan",
                PersNr = 870603,
                BioPappa = "Jarmo",
                Adress = new Adress
                {
                    Land = "Sverige",
                    PostNr = 73249,
                    Stad = "Arboga"
                }
            });

            dict.Add(840615, new Person
            {
                Name = "Lina",
                PersNr = 840615,
                BioPappa = "Erik"
            });
            return dict;

        }



namespace WindowsFormsApplication148
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Person.Metod();


            var person = myDic[int.Parse(textBoxSok.Text)];




            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Name);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.PersNr);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.BioPappa);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.Stad);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.PostNr);
            listBox1.Items.Add(person.Adress.Land);




        }
```

Comment: what is `myDic`? Where it's initialized?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var myDic = Person.Metod();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your method (Please use a more meaningful and less confusing name) you need to receive the result of its work

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Dictionary<int, Person> myDic = person.Metod();
        var person = myDic[int.Parse(textBoxSok.Text)];
        .......
```

However you haven't shown all of your code because, as shown in your question the code doesn't compile. I suppose that you have somewhere declared AND INITIALIZED the variable `myDic` because you need to use it in different parts of your forms. This is somewhat to be analyzed better because the call to `Metod` reinitializes the local variable `myDic` to the Dictionary returned by the method call.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //WRONG
        Person.Metod();
```

You execute a method but do not assign the result to anything.

Comment: Thanks for this explination !